# Implementation of two-type version of boost `less_than`

Tags: c++, boost

Based on [pp130](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321133544)

> However, it would be nice to also have a version that supports
>   comparisons between T and compatible types, which is simply a case of
>   adding more overloads. **For symmetry, you need to allow either type to
>   be on the left side of the operation**. (This is easy to forget when
>   adding operators manually; one tends to only see clearly the fact that
>   the right side must accept the other type. Of course, your two-type
>   version of less_than wouldn't make such silly mistakes, right?)

```
template <class T,class U>
class less_than2
{
public:
  friend bool operator<=(const T& lhs,const U& rhs) { 
    return !(lhs>rhs); 
  }

  friend bool operator>=(const T& lhs,const U& rhs) { 
    return !(lhs<rhs); 
  }

  friend bool operator>(const U& lhs,const T& rhs) {
    return rhs<lhs; 
  }

  friend bool operator<(const U& lhs,const T& rhs)  { 
    return rhs>lhs; 
  }

  friend bool operator<=(const U& lhs,const T& rhs) { 
    return !(rhs<lhs); 
  }

  friend bool operator>=(const U& lhs,const T& rhs) { 
    return !(rhs>lhs); 
  }
};
```

**Question**> Why we don't have to provide the following two functions?

```
  friend bool operator>(const T& lhs,const U& rhs) {
    return rhs<lhs; 
  }

  friend bool operator<(const T& lhs,const U& rhs)  { 
    return rhs>lhs; 
  }
```

Comment: I haven't read the book, but at first glance I don't see why less_than2 is providing more than just less-than operations.

Answer (score 1):

This operator:

```
friend bool operator>=(const T& lhs,const U& rhs) { 
  return !(lhs<rhs); 
}
```

depends on the validity of the function call `lhr<rhs`. Providing its signature second time by your `operator<(const T&, const U&)` doesn't make sense (it's even wrong).

Same applies to the second overload.